# Цикл создания textbox'ов в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Создал форму и на ней текстбокс для ввода определенного числа и кнопку для подтверждения введенных данных + для перехода на новую форму, где также есть кнопка, но для формирования новых текстбоксов. Их количество равно тому числу, что я вводил ранее на первой форме. Как реализовать данный цикл создания этих текстбоксов?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант:

```
n = 5 # число новых текстбоксов
for i in range(n):
    text = Text(width = 30, height = 1)
    text.insert('1.0', i)
    text.place(x = 50, y = 25*i)
```

[image: Пример окна]

Comment: А зациклить появление и закрытие формы по тому же числу из текстбокса возможно?

Comment: Немного не понял Ваш вопрос. Можете написать немного подробнее?

Comment: Сейчас постараюсь обьяснить. У меня на первой форме есть текстбокс и кнопка, которая подтверждает введенную в этот текстбокс информацию (то есть число) + создает новую форму, где также есть текстбоксы для ввода информации и еще одна кнопка для подтверждения, при нажатии на которую данная форма закрывается и открывается снова с теми же элементами формы. Количество закрытий и открытий данной формы должно быть равно тому числу, что я ввел в текстбокс первой формы.

Comment: Теперь понятно, но думаю, Вам лучше задать новый вопрос, чтобы не разводить флейм под уже существующим.